# Should I Leave Django Allauth As-Is Or Make The Changes I've Suggested

Tags: django, security, django-allauth

Im using Django Allauth and have a number of questions.

(a) When a user registers they are instantly logged in and a confirmation email is sent to their inbox. I am wondering if this is best practice? Should the user instead be signed out after registration and only allowed to sign in using the link in their email?

I am also wondering about password change. The password change functionality that comes with Allauth simply asks the user to enter their old password then enter a new one twice. My two questions for this are (b) is this good practice or should I make my users request a new password via email, and (c) should I force logout my users after a password change and make them login using their new credentials?

(d) And lastly, if a user has forgotten their password they can request a new one sent to them via email. I could imagine this could easily be abused as you do not need to be signed in to do this (a person or bot continually enter a users email address sending them thousands of password reset links). Is there a way to add a limit on a persons email address so the one user can only be sent maybe 2 password reset links per day?

I would appreciate answers to any of these questions and greatly appreciate any elaboration on how to do any of this as I am new to Django and really dont know where to begin if I am to make these changes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want to do, if your site is gonna manage a lot privacy data, then the story would be completely different. Assuming that it is true.

A) Best practice would be to be able to log in right away but they have restriction until they confirm the email.

B)Always request password change via Email using generated url.

C)You should not keep the user logged in with the old password, either log it out or automatic re login.

D)This is probably the most important here. There is a lot of way to prevent such abuse, tho they are not 100% effective but it is very effective, here is the thing: 1) if your way to recover password is by email, you can KEEP THE EMAIL PRIVATE, no one can see it, and what do you think the odds are to type a random email and matches the one on your database ? 2) Use popular antibots like Google's Recaptcha. 3) Set a limit of attempts on a limited range of time.